# Internal Linking Plugin or code

Tags: plugins

IS there a plugin or code that I could do the following

1. Choose a term, lets say Apple Ipad
2. Then that Apple Ipad term would automatically link to a post that also has those terms
3. The ability to pick terms and posts it links too be cool

such thing out there?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one I wrote that does this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-auto-linker/

It's in a very early version and it's okay. Still kind of buggy (as you can see by the forum comments), but getting better as people give me feedback.

There's also SEO Smart Links http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-automatic-links/

Comment: both interesting, so with yours  I can state which keyword to go and find. so lets say i have a post about hmmm sony radios, i type in sony radios somewhere and it goes and finds similiar posts and interlinks them?  this all on the fly or is it altering the database?

Comment: No you give it the keyword sony radios and then specify what url those keywords should link to.  It doesn't do it for you automatically.  If that's more what you want, look into related posts plugins.